# .net localhost url to server as redirect for hosts file entry

Tags: iis, localhost, hosts

I want to use something like http://localhost:6240 as entry in win hosts file.

For example when developing locally, I want when I'll open this domain dev.mysite.com the browser to navigate to http://localhost:6240

Answer (score 0):

The Windows or any `hosts` file doesn't know anything about ports. There is no way to redirect traffic on that level.

Don't use ports, add `dev.mysite.com` to your `hosts` file and also as a host-header binding to the IIS site you want use.

You could also try to add URL-rewrite-rules and redirect request to a different site, but that is much more complicated.